# Variable references in ruby

Tags: ruby, reference, pass-by-reference, copy-on-write

So apparently it seems that ruby is a pass-by reference language:

```
$ irb --simple-prompt 
>> @foo=1
=> 1
>> @bar=2
=> 2
>> @foo.object_id
=> 3
>> @bar.object_id
=> 5
>> [@foo,@bar].each {|e| puts e.object_id }
3
5
=> [1, 2]
```

I.e., both the constructed array and the block seem to deal with references to the original class instance variable objects.

However, these references seem to create copies as soon as I try to write into them:

```
>> [@foo,@bar].each {|e| puts e+=1 }
2
3
=> [1, 2]
>> @foo
=> 1
>> @bar
=> 2
>> [@foo,@bar].map! {|e| e+1 }
=> [2, 3]
>> @foo
=> 1
>> @bar
=> 2
```

I had a handful of class instance variable objects that I needed to transform via a function so I thought I'd save keystrokes by making use of the pass-by-reference thing and do something like:

```
[@var1, @var2, @var3].map! {|v| my_function(v) }
```

but it doesn't seem to work due to this copy-on-write thing that seems to be going on.

Is there a way to turn it off?
How would you accomplish my while keeping the code both DRY and efficient at the same time?

Comment: Interesting question!! But I don't understand, what your goal is.. :( Can you write your expectation please ?

Comment: I dont understand the question.  Can you point out on what line the unexpected behavior occurs, and what you expected it to be?

Comment: Maybe the misunderstanding is, that you think you write to the instance variables (`@foo`) with `map!`. `map!` only modifies the array, it does not change the instance variables used to construct the array.

Comment: Basically, I want to process a bunch of variables (that are not part of an array) in a uniform fashion without having to repeat myself.

I could do :
var1 = my_function(var1)
var2 = my_function(var2)
...
But that's not very DRY and can be quite lengthy if the var/function names are long.

[var1, var2, var3].map! {|v| my_function(v) }
on the other hand is very DRY, but it creates a transient copy, and the original variables don't change.

My point is that it should be technically possible to get them to change, since the object_id's inside the block are the same as outside of it.

Comment: "So apparently it seems that ruby is a pass-by reference language" Nope. Ruby is 100% pass-by-value. There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby.

Comment: If the passed variable inside my function returns the same object_id, I call that pass-by-reference. If you're judging it based on behavior, then I'd say it's a mixture of both. I wouldn't call a language where `a="foo"; def change(str); str.upcase!; end; change(a); a ` returns "FOO"  a 100% pass-by-value language. In any case, this question is about achieving a particular goal, not about quibbling over terminology. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
@foo = 1
@bar = 2
instance_variables.each do |var| 
  instance_variable_set(var,instance_variable_get(var)+1)
end
@foo # => 2
@bar # => 3
```

Comment: @ThorX89 I thought, that answer is enough to help you to reach to your goal.. I was confused about your need. :) :)

Comment: Actually, it was. Thank you. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is pass-by-value, always. But in some cases this value is a pointer (which, I guess, some consider pass-by-reference).

#### Edit:

Building on Arup's answer, here's a version that processes only some ivars.

```
[:@foo, :@bar].each do |var| 
  instance_variable_set(var, myfunction(instance_variable_get(var)))
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It occurred to me too, after I had written my comment on Arup's answer. :-)

Comment: Ruby really isn't pass-by-value, it's pass-by-reference and a few objects (numbers, booleans, etc.) have special treatment since their instances can't be modified. Anyway, that isn't the reason why their code wasn't working. `+=` and `map!` wouldn't change the objects in the array even if they were regular pass-by-reference objects!

Comment: @Max: if it was pass-by-reference, methods would be able to return values through arguments. Which they can't. Ergo, it's pass-by-value.

Comment: Also, you seem to be confusing "passing a pointer to function" with "passing a reference to function". These are two different things.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The difficulty here I think is the definition of "reference". Ruby is certainly not pass by reference in the sense of C++.

Comment: @Max: Yes, exactly. :)

Comment: @Max: You are wrong. Ruby is absolutely pass-by-value. There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby. Period.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is *pass-by-value only*. There is no pass-by-reference in Ruby. Every value in Ruby is a *reference* (a pointer to an object). So `@foo` is a pointer to an object, `@bar` is a pointer to an object, `@foo.object_id` is a pointer to an object, etc. "Objects" are not values in Ruby. All values in Ruby are passed or assigned by value.

In the first piece of code, you are accessing methods of the object pointed to by each reference. If you pass or assign the reference, you will have a new copy of the reference, but of course it points to the same object as the original reference.

In the second piece of code, you are assigning to the local copy of the reference to make it point to something else. This of course does not change what object the reference in the original scope pointed to.

Comment: Ruby really can be both. Depending on how you define "reference", of course. It's just another flamewar we rubyists engage in to spend time :)

Comment: I, former C programmer, have one definition of reference. But all these kids nowadays who never had to dereference a pointer - they think reference is something else. :)